# Migrate to Web Applications

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

I just wanted to flag [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18405962/1536038) as off-topic, with the migrate option to Web Applications, but it's not there (anymore?).

Should I flag for a Moderator instead?

Comment: Flag for moderator attention.  I don't think WebApps was ever on the list (and feature requests to add more sites to the list rarely go well).

Comment: I'm not sure WebApps would appreciate that question there, on the grounds of quality.

Comment: @AndrewBarber the questions is pretty straightforward but defenitely WebApps worthy.

Comment: @AndrewBarber It seems like a real, albeit simple question. How is it low quality? Easy, yes, bad, not at all.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Was the option to migrate to WebApps available before the new flagging setup?

Comment: The 5 "blessed" migration destinations have changed many times, mostly after sites on the list campaigned long and hard to have themselves *removed* because of too much crap being migrated their direction. I have no idea if Web Apps was ever on the list or not, but we try to keep the list very narrow and rather foolproof. If you see a good question that is off-topic for Stack Overflow that you think should be migrated somewhere that is *not* on the list, raise a flag on it using the "other" option. Lots of discussion about this on Meta already; use the search feature.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for your comments !! I used Meta becasue I was sure the option was there before. Now I'm not sure anymore....

Comment: Don't misinterpret me as saying it's an invalid question, of course. Perfectly reasonable to ask, and thanks for taking the time to care about such things! Programmers, for example, used to be on the list, as did Server Fault. Though they are fairly obvious destinations, they complained about getting too many bad migrations and eventually their requests to be removed were heeded. If you see a question that you *really* think belongs there, your only choice is to flag it. But the reality is that most of the time, questions that get asked on the wrong site aren't good enough to migrate. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate action in your case would be to flag the question for moderator attention and to mention that the question is appropriate for another site in the Network.

In case you believe, that the moderator has taken an incorrect decision, **then** you should bring it up on meta as you have done for the specific linked question. This will either clear out any confusions you or others may have regarding the exact scope boundaries and/or also draw attention to the specific case. In fact, the linked question has already been migrated.